# Filtering data in Django ORM

Tags: python, django-orm

I need to get data from the field leaved_at.
I'm trying to get data about active passes, that is, those where there is nothing in the leaved_at field.

Here is my code in models.py:

`

```
class Visit(models.Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        passcard = models.ForeignKey(Passcard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        entered_at = models.DateTimeField()
        leaved_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

`

I tried:

`

```
active = Visit.objects.filter(leaved_at=True)
print(active)
```

`

This doesn't work. How can I get this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
active_visits = Visit.objects.filter(leaved_at__isnull=True)
```